# Object value being over written by last value on the Loop

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have following input data:

```
{
   'a': [1, 2, 3],
   'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
   'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
}
```

I am trying to change above input data into following data structure:

```
{ 
  '0': { a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'a' },
  '1': { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'b' },
  '2': { a: 3, b: 'z', c: 'c' }
}
```

My Javascript Code is:

```
let parentDataset = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
} 

let children = {};
let parent = {};

for (let key in parentDataset) {

  let i = 0;
  for (let value of parentDataset[key]) {        
    children[key] = value;
    parent[i] = children;
    i++;
  }
}

console.log('parent', parent);
```

But I am getting following output where last value is over writing previous two values as below:

```
{ 
  '0': { a: 3, b: 'z', c: 'c' },
  '1': { a: 3, b: 'z', c: 'c' },
  '2': { a: 3, b: 'z', c: 'c' }
}
```

Any solution and explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Declare children inside the loop

Comment: Nope, it give be following output: parent { '0': { c: 'a' }, '1': { c: 'b' }, '2': { c: 'c' } }

Comment: All three, 0 1 and 2, are storing the same `children` object. you need a new one for each. you'll have to reorganize the loop a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to reduce object's values. For example:

```
const data = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
}

const result = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, subarr, idx, arr) => {
  return { ...acc, [idx]: arr.map(sub => sub[idx]) }
}, {})
```

Answer (score 4):

After getting the list of keys, you can [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) one of the arrays to a series of objects, and populate them using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const obj = {
   'a': [1, 2, 3],
   'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
   'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
};

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

const result = obj[keys[0]].reduce((r, _, i) => {
  const o = r[i] = {};
  
  keys.forEach((key) => Object.assign(o, { [key]: obj[key][i] }));

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

And here is a working version of your code:

```js
const parentDataset = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
} 

const parent = {};

for (const key in parentDataset) {
  let i = 0;
  
  for (const value of parentDataset[key]) {        
    !parent[i] && (parent[i] = {}); // create a new object if one is needed
    parent[i][key] = value; // add the key and value to the object
    i++;
  }
}

console.log('parent', parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c']
};

const output = {};

Object.keys(input).forEach( key => {
  input[key].forEach((value,i) => {
    if( !output[i] ){
       output[i] = { [key] : value };
    } else {
       output[i][key] = value;
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you will have to loop through the given objects keys and values.

Below is the small code-snippet:

```js
var data = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
};


function addKeys(keys, values, index) {
  var subObj = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    subObj[keys[i]] = values[i][index]
  }
  return subObj
}

function returnFinalObject(data) {
  var keys = Object.keys(data)
  var values = Object.values(data)
  var obj = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    obj[i] = addKeys(keys, values, i)
  }
  return (obj)
}

var finalObj = returnFinalObject(data)

console.log(finalObj)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

With [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) twice:

```js
var o = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3],
  'b': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
};

var transposed = Object.keys(o).reduce((res, key, i, arr) => {
  res[i] = arr.reduce((row, key) => {
    row[key] = o[key][i];
    return row;
  }, {});
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(transposed);
```